# How can I convert duration to int or nat in archetype?

Tags: smart-contracts, archetype

Or: How can I multiply duration and tez? (I need tez as my output)

I would usually write something about what I have tried - but I don't really know where to start with this one. I have looked through the archetype docs searching for 'convert' and looking at the [arithmetic table](https://archetype-lang.org/docs/reference/expressions/operators/arithmetic/#a--b-1) but I can't find anything that would allow this.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to divide by `1s`, for example:

```
transfer (d/1s * balance) to grum
```

where `d` is a duration value; the division of duration returns a rational, and you can multiply rational by tez.